# Execute external powershell script in jenkins pipleline

Tags: powershell, groovy

I was trying to execute powershell script in a remote machine via jenkins pipeline.my script location ex: $server_vm_name\d$\scripts\testscript.ps1 . and I need to pass parameter to the testscript.ps1 as parameter name -clientpath. for the client path u have used this external path ex:
\${client_vm_name}\d$\Client\Application . I have used the network paths for both script location and parameter

I have write the following code snippet to get the work done. but its not working. anyone have idea what i have done in wrong way?.
error msg :

*

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 885: unexpected char: '\' @ line 885, column 49.
   rshell  script: "\\$db_vm_name\d$\script
```

- 

```
  stage('Installation') {
          
          agent{
            label PS_AGENT_LABEL
          }
          
          steps{
            script{

              powershell  script: "\\$server_vm_name\d$\scripts\testscript.ps1 -clientPath \\${client_vm_name}\d$\Client\Application"
              
             
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: how do you know that it does not work? do you have an error message?

Comment: added the error msg in the description of the issue now.

Comment: so, fix the error: each '\' must be escaped: '\\', also you have `d$` - it should be `d\$` because `$` it does not represent a variable in this case...